# bootstrap-input-spinner-Angular: How to add 24 format in the below code

Tags: jquery, angular

I need time in 24 formats like 2:30. Please help with the below code. Added script file in this code. how to write this one.

I referred to the online code in the bootstrap input spinner. https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-input-spinner  In this link, need timeeditor option.

```
 <input type="number" value="4.5" min="0" max="9" step="0.1" data-decimals="2" data-suffix="°C"/>

var props = {
    decrementButton: "<strong>&minus;</strong>", // button text
    incrementButton: "<strong>&plus;</strong>", // ..
    groupClass: "", // css class of the resulting input-group
    buttonsClass: "btn-outline-secondary",
    buttonsWidth: "2.5rem",
    textAlign: "center", // alignment of the entered number
    autoDelay: 500, // ms threshold before auto value change
    autoInterval: 50, // speed of auto value change
    buttonsOnly: false, // set this `true` to disable the possibility to enter or paste the number via keyboard
    keyboardStepping: true, // set this to `false` to disallow the use of the up and down arrow keys to step
    locale: navigator.language, // the locale, per default detected automatically from the browser
    editor: TimeEditor, // the editor (parsing and rendering of the input)
    template: // the template of the input
        '<div class="input-group ${groupClass}">' +
        '<div class="input-group-prepend"><button style="min-width: ${buttonsWidth}" class="btn btn-decrement ${buttonsClass} btn-minus" type="button">${decrementButton}</button></div>' +
        '<input type="text" inputmode="decimal" style="text-align: ${textAlign}" class="form-control form-control-text-input"/>' +
        '<div class="input-group-append"><button style="min-width: ${buttonsWidth}" class="btn btn-increment ${buttonsClass} btn-plus" type="button">${incrementButton}</button></div>' +
        '</div>'
}
 var inputSpinnerCustomEditors = {
   
    
    TimeEditor: function (props, element) {
        // could be implemented more elegant maybe, but works
        this.parse = function (customFormat) {
            var trimmed = customFormat.trim()
            var sign = 1
            if (trimmed.charAt(0) === "-") {
                sign = -1
                trimmed = trimmed.replace("-", "")
            }
            var parts = trimmed.split(":")
            var hours = 0, minutes
            if (parts[1]) {
                hours = parseInt(parts[0], 10)
                minutes = parseInt(parts[1], 10)
            } else {
                minutes = parseInt(parts[0], 10)
            }
            return (hours * 60 + minutes) * sign
        }
        this.render = function (number) {
            var minutes = Math.abs(number % 60)
            if (minutes < 10) {
                minutes = "0" + minutes
            }
            var hours
            if (number >= 0) {
                hours = Math.floor(number / 60)
                return hours + ":" + minutes
            } else {
                hours = Math.ceil(number / 60)
                return "-" + Math.abs(hours) + ":" + minutes
            }
        }
    }
}
$("#TimeEditor").inputSpinner({editor: inputSpinnerCustomEditors.TimeEditor})
```

Comment: I referred to this page https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-input-spinner?activeTab=readme     Please help

Comment: There is a section time editor. Didn't you find anything useful? However, I would not recommend you to use it with Angular

Comment: I used that function but getting timeeditor is not defined

Comment: What is the implementation of this code in your project, i.e. how do you use it? What are the error messages?

Comment: Getting this error "<a class='gotoLine' href='#140:18'>140:18</a> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).inputSpinner is not a function"
"Script error."

Comment: I need dropdown like 1:00 up and down arrows(bootstrap time spinner)

Comment: There is a working axample on the Demo Page https://shaack.com/projekte/bootstrap-input-spinner/ under "Custom Editors > TimeEditor"